# string does not name a type in header file

Tags: string, types

i've seen alot of topics like this that said to simply change your variables like this:

```
#include <string>
 void function(string name, int number);
```

to:

```
#include <string>
void function(std::string name, int number);
```

But i already done this but it isnt working, here is my code:

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
class personnage {
 public:
   personnage();

   void heal(int amount);
   void attack(personnage &target);
   void changeweapon(string name, int dmg);
   void receivedmg(int amount);
   bool isAlive();

private:
int m_vie;
string m_weapon;
int m_weaponDamage;
};


#endif // PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Is there anyone knowing what to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? If you have any specific compiler errors or any bugs, please be specific and post them.